# Sharepoint List VAlidation setting

Tags: validation, site-settings, shareoint

I am trying to add validation for my share point lists. I have List with items containing some fields `[Delete Item]` ,`[Scored Status]` and some other. I want if the item is scored than user should not be allowed to select the check box for field `[Delete Item]`. So I am using following formula for same but it doesn't work:

```
=IF([Delete Item]="Yes",
IF([Scored Status]="Scored", FALSE, TRUE),TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the validation formula to the List Validation, not the Column Validation.

List/Library Settings, List Validation

If the [Delete Item] column is a Yes/No then try this:

```
=IF( [Delete Item],
 IF( [Scored Status]="Scored", FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

And you should be able to shorten the above to:

```
=NOT( AND( [Delete Item], [Scored Status]="Scored" ) )
```

Comment: Thanks it helped.